# How does the stoichiometric coefficient affect the time until a given percentage of the reactant is consumed (if at all)?

Tags: kinetics, concentration, rate-equation

#### Problem from Serway's College Physics test bank:

---

The reaction $2NO_2\rightarrow2NO+O_2$ obeys the rate law:

$\large \frac{\Delta[O_2]}{\Delta t} = (1.40\times10^{-2})[NO_2]^2 \space at \space 500^\circ \space K $

If the initial concentration of $NO_2$ is 1.00 M, how long will it take for the [$NO_2$] to decrease to 35.8% of its initial value?

A) 45.9 s

B) 73 s

C) 128 s

D) 1.40 x 10<sup>-2</sup> s

E) cannot be determined from this data

**ANSWER: C**

---

#### My work

We are given the reaction rate for $O_2$. Since for a given reaction $aA + bB \rightarrow cC + dD$, the rate of the reaction $r = -\frac{1}{a}\frac{d[A]}{dt} = -\frac{1}{b}\frac{d[B]}{dt} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{d[C]}{dt} = \frac{1}{d}\frac{d[D]}{dt}$, I conclude that $\frac{\Delta[O_2]}{\Delta t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta[NO_2]}{\Delta t} \Rightarrow -\frac{\Delta[NO_2]}{\Delta t} = 2\frac{\Delta[O_2]}{\Delta t}$. Therefore:

$-\frac{\Delta[NO_2]}{\Delta t} = 2 \times (1.40\times10^{-2})[NO_2]^2 = (2.8\times10^{-2})[NO_2]^2 \Rightarrow$

$\textbf k = 2.8\times10^{-2}$

Knowning that the reaction is second-order in $NO_2$, I plug in $[NO_2] = 0.358[NO_2]_0$ into the integrated rate law and solve for t as so:

$\frac{1}{0.358[NO_2]_0} = kt + \frac{1}{[NO_2]_0}$

$\frac{1}{0.358\times1M} - \frac{1}{1M} = 2.8\times10^{-2}\times t$

$t \approx 64 s$

---

#### Answer given in the test bank

However, the textbook gives 128s as the answer, indicating that the reaction rate was NOT multiplied by 2 (from $\frac{\Delta[O_2]}{\Delta t}$ to $-\frac{\Delta[NO_2]}{\Delta t}$).

Is there a gap in my understanding of conversion between reaction rates according to the stoichiometric coefficient of the reactant/product being handled or did the test bank simply give an incorrect answer?

Comment: @Poutnik. No. If $t = 0$, the coefficient of $\ce{[NO2]_0}$  cannot be $0.358$. $t$ is not a variable in this equation.

Comment: @Poutnik. This is an equation with one unknown, $t$, which is dependent on the numerical value $0.358$. $t$ cannot be chosen at will.

Comment: @Maurice  Variables are independent and dependent, with the former possibly masked by literal value substitution. But I guess we have cleared the things and I am going to purge the related comments.

Comment: Procedural advice: Always try to stay at symbolic algebraic expressions as long as possible and apply literal values only in the last minute when you already have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not multiply the rate constant by an stoichiometric coefficient.

The rate of this chemical reactionis given by

$$ v = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{d|NO2_2|}{{dt}} = +\frac{1}{2}\frac{d|NO|}{{dt}} = +\frac{1}{1}\frac{d|O2_2|}{{dt}} = k |NO_2|^2 $$

where k is the reaction rate constant. In your exercise, $k = 1,4\times10^{-2} \;mol^{-1}\,dm^3\,s^{-1}$.

Notice that the stoichimetric coefficients appear in the reaction rate definition, thus the reaction rate does not depend on which reactant or product used to obtain it.

Comment: Check, for example, Atkins, P., De Paula, J., & Keeler, J. (2017). Atkins’ physical chemistry (11th ed.). Oxford University Press. You hava definitions and examples in section _22.2a The rates of reactions. The definition of rate_